# Cloning an Element before CSS Transition returns the Element with transitions applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is to clone some elements before CSS3 Transitions are applied (before adding the class).

On `$(window).load()` I clone the elements and then add the new class which should kick the transitions.

After removing the previous elements with `.remove()`, I `.append()` the clone hoping it will contain the original elements without the transition effects, but this isn't what happening.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="start">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="1- Remove Elements" id="remove"/>
<input type="button" value="2- Generate" id="generate" />
```

**CSS**

```
.start {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transition: background 4s;
    -moz-transition: background 4s;
    transition: background 4s;
}
.end {
    background: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var clone = "";

$(window).load(function(){
    clone = $("#parent").children("div");
    $("#parent").children("div").addClass("end");
});

$("#remove").click(function(){
     $("#parent").children("div").remove();
});

$("#generate").click(function(){
    $("#parent").append(clone);
});
```

I made a full example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gv93G/

### UPDATE

I missed checking the result after adding the class again, it doesn't work as expected  check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QeVF6/

After fetching back the clone, I add the class, and the transitions are applied instantaneously.

**What I need is to apply the transitions but not instantaneously, I want to see the same `4sec` effect on the newly appended clone.**

Comment: Always include the relevant code **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `clone = $("#parent").children("div")` doesn't create a copy of the matched elements, but stores the returned list into a variable.

In order to create a copy of matched elements, you should use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method as follows:

```
clone = $("#parent").children("div").clone();
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Gv93G/1/)**.

### Update

I was under this assumption that you don't want to apply the transition on the cloned elements.

If you want to set a delay between elements to trigger the transition, you can use [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/) and [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) methods as follows:

```
$("#generate").click(function() {
    $("#parent").append(clone);

    $("#parent").children("div").delay(4000).queue(function() {
        $(this).addClass("end").dequeue(); // move to the next queue item
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/QeVF6/2/)**

Comment: I missed checking the result after adding the class again, it doesn't work as expected `:(` check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QeVF6/    After fetching back the clone, I add the class, and the transitions are applied instantaneously.

Comment: @AliBassam By `$("#parent").children("div")` you're selecting the appended elements too. You should change the order of the last two lines as: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/QeVF6/1/

Comment: Yes but the transitions aren't applied, what I need is to apply the transitions but not instantaneously, I want to see the same `4sec` effect on the newly appended clone.

Comment: Ah.. I was under this assumption that you don't want to apply the transition on the cloned elements. Okay then, let me check.

Comment: My Bad I should have explained more, I will write another question about this problem

Comment: @AliBassam No need to post another question. I just updated the answer to fit your needs.