# CSS3 Transitions are applied instantaneously on Cloned Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some elements that I'm applying CSS3 Transitions on by adding a new class.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.child {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transition: background 4s;
    -moz-transition: background 4s;
    transition: background 4s;
}

.newChild {
   background: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".child").addClass("newChild");
```

When I clone the `.child` element before adding the new class, and then I add the new class, transitions are applied immediately, not after `4sec`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2grW/).

Comment: just for the record: apply the classname only, without a leading dot: .addClass("classname") and not ".classname".

Comment: @Alex sorry mistakes when I type fast.

Comment: You are cloning the child element, but no animation is applied, is that intentional?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I want to apply the transitions on the cloned elements, but they are applied instantaneously not after `4sec`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141758/cloning-an-element-before-css-transition-returns-the-element-with-transitions-ap/22141848#22141848):

If you want to set a delay between elements to trigger the transition, you can use [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/) and [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) methods as follows:

```
$("#generate").click(function() {
    $("#parent").append(clone);

    $("#parent").children("div").delay(4000).queue(function() {
        $(this).addClass("end").dequeue(); // move to the next queue item
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/QeVF6/2/)**

### Updated

Per your comment, you should remove the `.end` class from the cloned elements when you remove the children by `$("#remove").click()`.

```
$("#remove").click(function(){
     $("#parent").children("div").remove();
    clone.removeClass('end');
});
```

The reason is you've defined the `clone` in global scope. Thus the cloned elements will have the `.end` class after adding the class by `$(this).addClass("end")`.

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/QeVF6/3/)**.

Comment: Hashem I think this is only working the first time, I don't know if there's something wrong with the original script, but It's not working again, try to remove again the new elements and then generate once again.

Comment: Both top answers suggested adding a delay but this one solves the problem once and for all. Thanks again Hashem.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the original question, there shouldn't be a delay of 4seconds, it should just transition from blue to red for 4seconds but immediately start... the original problem is that the cloned object immediately gets the transitioned state of red.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a little timeout, the document gets altered too fast:

```
var clone;

$(window).load(function(){
     clone = $("#parent").children("div").clone();
     $("#parent").children("div").addClass("newChild");
});

$("#remove").click(function(){
     $("#parent").children("div").remove();
});

$("#generate").click(function(){
    $("#parent").append(clone);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#parent").children("div").addClass("newChild");
    }, 30);

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2grW/2/)

Comment: The fiddle looks better but this really isn't clear. Is that a browser bug or what ?

Comment: Why would the timeout prevent the two transitions to be synchronized ? Especially as a timeout of 0ms is enough, which means this **isn't** about the delay. This really looks like a browser bug to me.

Comment: Works the first time but not the second time, try to remove the cloned elements again and then generate for a second time.

Comment: you cant make a transition when you append an element because you are setting its display, no parallel transitioning is possible, only after appending an element. setting a timeout covers that little moment when the browser has refreshed the dom

Comment: have a look at this: http://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/

Comment: I'm fairly confident you can actually set a timeout of 0. Any setTimeout will cause the class change to hit on another frame and not the one where the HTML is being appended. When it comes to rendering or CSS reflow-tripping stuff, assume everything in a function will happen at the same time, but not necessarily in the order you want or by the time an appended element, for instance, is ready to have changes applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your transition on newChild:

```
.newChild {
    background: red;
   -webkit-transition: background 4s;
   -moz-transition: background 4s;
   transition: background 4s;
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CqyJi)</kbd>

Comment: I tested, it doesn't seem to work. Please make a fiddle.

Comment: This is making the transition lasting for 4s, not delaying for 4s *before* applying the transition... not that this deserves to be flagged like it has been, imho, but pay attention to the specifics of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `.delay(), .queue() and .dequeue()` should be used:

```
$("#generate").click(function(){
    $("#parent").append(clone);
    $("#parent").children("div").delay(1).queue(function() {
       $(this).addClass("newChild").dequeue();
    });
});
```